# Understanding the equation $U(1+\delta\omega)=I+\frac{i}{2\hbar}\delta\omega_{cd}M^{cd}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am paraphrasing the following fact from Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory textbook. For an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^a_b=\delta^a_b+\delta\omega^a_b$, we associate the unitary operator $U(1+\delta\omega)=I+\frac{i}{2\hbar}\delta\omega_{cd}M^{cd}$.

1. Is $U(\Lambda)=U(1+\delta\omega)$ supposed to be a matrix or just a function?
2. In the definition $U(1+\delta\omega)=I+\frac{i}{2\hbar}\delta\omega_{cd}M^{cd}$, it seems that $I$ is a matrix and $\delta\omega_{cd}M^{cd}$. How does this make sense? Does $M^{cd}$ have hidden indices?

Answer (score 1):

The $M^{cd}$ are abstract *operators* that map abstract vectors in a Hilbert space to other abstract vectors.

If the abstract vectors in Hilbert space are represented as concrete functions on spacetime, then the abstract $M^{cd}$ are represented as concrete differential operators involving $\partial/\partial t$, $\partial/\partial x$, etc., and the identity operator $I$ is represented as multiplication-by-one.

If you choose a basis in Hilbert space and represent the abstract vectors as a (possibly infinite-sized) column of complex numbers — the components of the vector in that basis — then the abstract $M^{cd}$ are represented as matrices acting on those column vectors and $I$ is represented by an identity matrix.

This kind of abstraction should be familiar from non-relativistic quantum mechanics, where sometimes the Hamiltonian is written as a differential operator and sometimes it is written as a matrix.

In short, what the $M^{cd}$ “look like” depends on what the vectors of your Hilbert space “look like”. But nothing important depends on any particular representation, so try to think about operators abstractly as just operators.

Comment: @JoshuaTS Thanks for your comment. I’ve updated my answer to talk about $I$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $U$ is an *operator*.  It acts on the Hilbert space of your system. You can think of it as a generalization of a matrix: it is a linear transformation on a vector space (in this case, your Hilbert space).  It is not *just* a matrix because your Hilbert space (the space of all your quantum states) may be infinite dimensional!  Operators behave very similar to matrices, for instance they do not necessarily commute.
2. Yes, $M^{cd}$ has hidden structure, each $M^{cd}$ is again an operator, as is $I$ and $U$.  $I$ is the identity operator in your Hilbert space, $\delta \omega_{cd}$ is a 4x4 matrix of numbers, and $M_{cd}$ is a 4x4 matrix of operators.

Comment: So $\delta\omega_{ab}M^{ab}$ is a function, and not a $4\times 4$ matrix, right?

Comment: @fierydemon Correct: it is normally an nxn matrix, if you are working in the n-dimensional representation of the Lorentz group. See, e.g., [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616332/unitary-infinitesimal-transformation).