# Unitary infinitesimal transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, angular-momentum, representation-theory

It is not clear to me how to show following is true.
$$U(1+\delta w)= I +\frac{i}{2}\delta w_{uv}M^{uv}$$
I have tried Taylor expanding this term using relation of unitary matrix to exponential function but there are terms that does not cancel out. I appreciate for any help.

Comment: Welcome to the Physics SE ! It would be a good idea to explain the symbols used and also include what you already tried.

Comment: $ \exp( i \delta w_{uv}M^{uv}/2)= I +\frac{i}{2}\delta w_{uv}M^{uv} +O(\delta w ^2), $ no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, This is the same  Taylor expansion that i was using which was $$ U(w)=exp(\frac{i}{2} w_{uv}M^{uv})$$ However, if I change w to $1+\delta w$, I am not sure how the "1" disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas! what you were using in your comment is wrong. I'll use self-explanatory notation for the relevant pseudo-orthogonal Lorentz matrices. (And [not all six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas) *M*s are hermitian,  but I won't fuss about pseudo-unitarity).

Indeed, a generic Lorentz transformation by generalized angles (which include boost parameters as well) is
$$
e^{{i\over 2} w\cdot M}= U(\Lambda )\neq U(w).
$$
That is, vanishing "angles" *w* imply *Λ*=I, and *U(1)=I*, in *this notation*.

For infinitesimal transformation "angles", what you have  is
$$
e^{{i\over 2} \delta w\cdot M}= I+ {i\over 2} \delta w\cdot M+ O(\delta w^2)=U(\Lambda )=U(1+\delta w) ,\\
\Lambda_{uv}= \eta_{uv} + \delta w_{uv}.
$$
So, for vanishing generalized "rotation", $\Lambda=I$, the 4×4 identity, and
$ U(1)= I$, the *n×n* identity, where *n* is the dimensionality of the representation of the Lorentz group  by the six *n×n* matrices   *M*. Even when *n=4*, the corresponding space could be  that of the spinor representation, not the vector rep acted upon by *Λ*!

This is a very different notation from the usual one, where *U* represents the group element indexed by its departure from the origin of angles; so, a vanishing angle amounts to the identity, $\exp (0) = I$, as you expected. In fact, here, $U(\Lambda)U(\Lambda')=U(\Lambda \Lambda')= U(1+\delta w + \delta w'+...)~$, which illustrates the nature of the notation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!